# How did my professor come up with this equation? Why is 1/i equal to a integral?

Tags: integration, complex-numbers

I just went trough the notes that my physics prof. put online and I came up a strange equation that I dont really now how to get to.

Basically he said, that $U_e/(i*\omega)$ is equal to some integral (equation is in the picture).

The topic is about an RC-Circuit acting as an Integrator and $U_e$ is the In-Voltage and $U_a$ is the Out-Voltage.

Would be great if someone could help me out with this one.

[The equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPQ8k.png)

Comment: What are the limits of integration?

Comment: Thanks for the hint below! I'm not really sure about the limits of integration, but I think I got it now. I guess he meant that $U_e$ is some periodic voltage and thus $$U_e = U_e * e^{i*\omega*t} $$ Which would then only leave me behind with the integration constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$\int e^{at} dt=\dfrac1a e^{at} + C $$